# Django moves compiled static file to STATIC_ROOT

Tags: django, sass, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I am running Django 2.1 and Python 3.6 in two projects and I am using `django-sass-processor` to compile my scss files.
I have a problem during development that after every change I have to run `./manage.py compilescss` to get my css files in correct location.
It is due to the fact that when I render a template that uses generated file this file is generated in `STATIC_ROOT` directory instead of next to `*.scss` file to which `localhost:8000/static/main.css` points.
After running `compilescss` it does properly compile next to `main.scss` file.

I have made a question to the library owner, but he states that this is django related problem so I am posting here.
In case someone would like to read: https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor/issues/110

Comment: I was facing the same issue or maybe it wasn't an issue. Here is what was happening: I followed the instructions to integrate django-sass-processor into my django project. When I was done with the instructions I created a sass file inside my static files folder and I was thinking that it would put that into the assets(my target folder to which my sass-processor was pointing to) folder and it didn't do anything. I ran `compilescss` and then it did put into target folder but it wasn't helpful. So after some time when I actually used/referenced my sass file in my html file it started compiling.

Comment: Above comment is probably just to give you some idea to reference your sass files correctly like documentation tells us to. check the usage section of django-sass-processor https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor#usage